# Use C# to declare HiddenField's value & Javascript Variable

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu, hiddenfield

I need to declare the 'text value' of the dropdownlist 'dropCallbackReason' into the 'ValueHiddenField' ID of the  so that I can then use it as a javascript variable.

I need to be able to declare the HiddenField through C# as aswell as declaring the Javascript Variable 'callBackReason' through c# as well, any ideas how to do this through C#?

.cs page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField { ID = "ValueHiddenField", Value = "test" };
        theForm.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
        string script = @"function updateCallBackReason() {
                callBackReason = document.getElementById('<%=ValueHiddenField.ClientID %>').value;
                return callBackReason;
            }";
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "callBackReasonScript", script, true);
```

.aspx

```
<asp:label runat="server" ID="lblCallbackReason" AssociatedControlID="dropCallbackReason" CssClass="textLabel">Reason for callback:</asp:label>
            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropCallbackReason" onChange="updateCallBackReason" ClientIDMode="Static" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select Reason --" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Booking a Test Drive" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Discussing a Purchase" Value="11"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Contract Hire Quotation" Value="45"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: So your question is how to do it through code-behind instead of declarative manner?

Comment: Yes Andrei, sorry If I waffled.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to add a `HiddenField` control programmatically. Note that controls cannot be added into `Page.Controls` directly - they should be placed into some container, like `ContentPlaceholder` or `Panel`:

```
HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField {ID = "ValueHiddenField", Value = "test"};
SomePanel.Controls.Add(hiddenField);
```

And here is how to register a script block:

```
string script = @"function updateCallBackReason() {
                    callBackReason = document.getElementById('<%=ValueHiddenField.ClientID %>').value;
                    return callBackReason;
                }";
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "callBackReasonScript", script, true);
```

Good places to do this are either `Page_Load` or `Page_PreRender`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I seem to get the compile error of ' System.Web.HttpException: The control collection cannot be modified during DataBind, Init, Load, PreRender or Unload phases.' Having a look around the web i don't seem to be able to find much idea why?

Comment: @wilsonlego, made a couple of edits to clarify the answer. Please see the update.

Comment: thank you, it's coming back with an error on the 'SomePanel.Controls.Add(hiddenField);' as SomePanel doesn't exists? Should I be using 'SomePanel'? Regards,

Comment: @wilsonlego, sure. `SomePanel` here is just an example of a control declared on the page. It can be anything. If you are using, say, content placeholders, you can use one of those here.

Comment: apologies. Well depending on which placeholder I use, i get either A#"does not allow child controls." B#Multiple controls with the same ID 'ValueHiddenField' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs. But I know I only use that ID once. hmm

Comment: @wilsonlego, it might help if you could post your code - currently I can only guess what problem are you facing.

Comment: thank you for your help so far. I have updating my code within my question at the top. Regards,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31648/discussion-between-wilsonlego-and-andrei)